# Initialize recogito/openseadrog-annotrious in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, typescript, annotations, angular9, openseadragon

i have one question about the initialization of annotorious-openseadragon plug-in for Angular 9.

In my case i work on a project that already have OSD viewer installed inside. I had try to install via npm this package: `npm i @recogito/annotorious-openseadragon`;
Then I made the import in this way inside my page: `import * as Annotorious from '@recogito/annotorious-openseadragon'`;
and finally I try to initialize it in this way: `const anno = Openseadragon.Annotorious(this.viewer, {});`.

well, now if I try to log my `const anno` I can see all the method attached on Annotorius (on, addAnnotation, selectAnnotation etc.) but I can't use it and i can't able also to draw my annotation on the image in the viewer.
Someone can help me please?

***osd.components.ts***:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnDestroy, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { uuid } from '../../utils/js-utils';

import * as Annotorious from '@recogito/annotorious-openseadragon';

declare var OpenSeadragon;

interface OsdAnnotation {
  id: string;
  element: HTMLElement;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  fontSize?: number;
  text: string;
  modalService?: NgbModal;
}

interface OsdAnnotationAPI {
  elements: OsdAnnotation[];
  getElements: () => OsdAnnotation[];
  getElementById: (id: string) => OsdAnnotation;
  addElement: (e: OsdAnnotation) => OsdAnnotation[];
  addElements: (es: OsdAnnotation[]) => OsdAnnotation[];
  removeElementById: (id: string) => void;
  removeElementsById: (ids: string[]) => void;
  goToElementLocation: (id: string) => void;
}

interface OsdViewerAPI {
  addHandler: (eventName: string, handler: (x: { page: number }) => void) => void;
  goToPage: (page: number) => void;
  viewport;
  gestureSettingsMouse;
  raiseEvent: (evtName: string) => void;
}

/*
From:
{
  "@id": "https://www.e-codices.unifr.ch:443/loris/bge/bge-gr0044/bge-gr0044_e001.jp2/full/full/0/default.jpg",
  "@type": "dctypes:Image",
  "format": "image/jpeg",
  "height": 7304,
  "width": 5472,
  "service": {
    "@context": "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
    "@id": "https://www.e-codices.unifr.ch/loris/bge/bge-gr0044/bge-gr0044_e001.jp2",
    "profile": "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level2.json"
  }
}

To:
{
  '@context': 'http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json',
  '@id': 'https://www.e-codices.unifr.ch/loris/bge/bge-gr0044/bge-gr0044_e001.jp2',
  'profile': ['http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level2.json'],
  'protocol': 'http://iiif.io/api/image',
  'height': 7304,
  'width': 5472,
}
*/
function manifestResourcetoTileSource(manifestResource) {
  return {
    '@context': manifestResource.service['@context'],
    '@id': manifestResource.service['@id'],
    profile: [manifestResource.service['@profile']],
    protocol: 'http://iiif.io/api/image',
    height: manifestResource.height,
    width: manifestResource.width,
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'evt-osd',
  templateUrl: './osd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./osd.component.scss'],
})
export class OsdComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('osd', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) div: ElementRef;

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  private _options;
  @Input() set options(v) { // TODO: add interface to better type this object
    if (v !== this._options) {
      this._options = v;
      this.optionsChange.next(this._options);
    }
  }
  get options() { return this._options; }
  optionsChange = new BehaviorSubject({});

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  private _manifestURL: string;
  @Input() set manifestURL(v: string) {
    if (v !== this._manifestURL) {
      this._manifestURL = v;
      this.manifestURLChange.next(this._manifestURL);
    }
  }
  get manifestURL() { return this._manifestURL; }
  manifestURLChange = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  private _page: number;
  @Input() set page(v: number) {
    if (v !== this._page) {
      this._page = v;
      this.pageChange.next(this._page);
    }
  }
  get page() { return this._page; }
  @Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  @Input() text: string;

  tileSources: Observable<Array<{}>> = this.manifestURLChange
    .pipe(
      filter((url) => !!url),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((url) => this.http.get<{ sequences: Partial<Array<{ canvases }>> }>(url)),
      map((manifest) => manifest // get the resource fields in the manifest json structure
        .sequences.map((seq) => seq.canvases.map((canv) => canv.images).reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), []))
        .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), []).map((res) => res.resource)
        .map(manifestResourcetoTileSource),
      ),
    );

  viewer: Partial<OsdViewerAPI>;
  viewerId: string;
  annotationsHandle: OsdAnnotationAPI;

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.pageChange.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe((x) => {
      if (!!this.viewer) {
        this.viewer.goToPage(x - 1);
      }
    }));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewerId = uuid('openseadragon');
    this.div.nativeElement.id = this.viewerId;

    const commonOptions = {
      visibilityRatio: 0.1,
      minZoomLevel: 0.5,
      defaultZoomLevel: 1,
      sequenceMode: true,
      prefixUrl: 'assets/osd/images/',
      id: this.div.nativeElement.id,
      navigatorBackground: '#606060',
      showNavigator: false,
      gestureSettingsMouse: {
        clickToZoom: false,
        dblClickToZoom: true,
      },
    };

    this.subscriptions.push(combineLatest([this.optionsChange, this.tileSources])
      .subscribe(([_, tileSources]) => {
        if (!!tileSources) {
          this.viewer = OpenSeadragon({
            ...commonOptions,
            tileSources,
          });
        } else {
          this.viewer = OpenSeadragon({
            ...commonOptions,
            ...this.options,
          });
        }

        this.viewer.addHandler('page', ({ page }) => {
          this.pageChange.next(page + 1);
        });
        const anno = Annotorious(this.viewer);
        console.log(anno);
      }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.unsubscribe());
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem with angular 14, OpenSeadragon 4.0.0 and @recogito/annotorious-openseadragon 2.7.10.
Did you find a solution?